# Time Delay not working in javascript code

Tags: javascript, timedelay

```
 for(;i<5;i++)
 {
 (function(z){
  setTimeout(function(){console.log(z);},2000);})(i);
 }
```

This prints  0 1 2 3 4 5 at one shot after 2sec.Why is it so? and what is the solution 
to print each number after 2 sec.

Comment: Increment the delay? `2000*i`

Comment: The timers all fire *at the same time* - remember that the setTimeout *returns immediately* (it is non-blocking) and so all the setTimeouts are *created at the same time* and are all set to fire at the same interval (2000ms) in the future from when they were created.

Comment: ok if i put 2000*i.It works.But if i put 2000+i it display at one shot.Why so?

Comment: 2000+i will fire afte 2 secs, 2 secs and one millisec, 2 secs and 2 millisecs. [Read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Comment: @user2246674.Can u please tell me what is meant by non-blocking?

Comment: @user2246674 - Note that they're not fired at literally the same time in the sense of multiple simultaneous threads. They're  independently _scheduled_ for the same time and then fired one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your timeouts needs to be spaced and I always use a different var to save each one in so I can clearTimeout on a specific one

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/a6j6a/)

```
var tIds=[];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
 (function(z){
    tIds[i]=setTimeout(function(){window.console&&console.log(z);},2000*i); //fire 2000,4000,6000
  })(i);
 }
```

Also Please [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to understand why 2000+i will not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code.

```
    //Referring your code for better understanding..
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
     (function(z){
      setTimeout(function(){console.log(z);},2000*z);})(i);
     }
```

Comment: It actually prints "1 2 3 4 5", not "0 1 2 3 4". Watch out the increment plz.

Comment: @neuront: Thanks for notifying my mistake..I updated that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are firing 5 **asynchronous** , almost simultaneous, invocations of the function.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` **won't block the execution** of your code for 2 seconds. In fact `setTimeout` returns immediately, and the loop continues. So all 5 of your async calls triggered at almost the same time after the timeout.

To approach what you want, I'd like this recursion-like version

```
function print(i) {
    if (i >= 5) return;

    console.log(i);
    setTimeout(function () {
        print(i + 1);
    }, 2000);
}

print(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try a diff approach using `setInterval`,

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){printThing();},2000);

var i = 0;    
function printThing(){
  if(i<=5){
    window.console && console.log(i);
    ++i;
  }
  else{
    clearInterval(timer)
  }
}//end function
```

heres an example http://jsfiddle.net/W9vS4/2/

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout(fn,delay)` runs a given function `fn` after delay `delay` in ms. So you can simply multiply `i` by 2000 and use:

```
for(;i<5;i++)  {
   setTimeout(function(){console.log(z);},2000*i);
}
```

If you want to report or use `i` within `fn`, you should create a function that returns a function for use in `setTimeout`, using a closure to report or use `i`. In the following `i` is enclosed using the variable `x`, used by the immediately invoked anonymous function creating the `f` function Object for subsequent use in `setTimeout`:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
   var f = function(x){
       return function(){console.log(z+'#'+x);}
   }(i);
   setTimeout(f,2000*i);
 }
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/k8N5u/)

Comment: But using 2000*i will increase the delay by 1 sec each time.So what can be done to print numbers at equal interval of time?

Comment: No, it will increase by 2 seconds (2000ms) each time. See the adjusted jsfiddle.